# Marshal nested structs into JSON

Tags: go, marshalling

How do I marshal a nested struct into JSON? I know how to marshal the struct without any nested structs. However when I try to make the JSON response look like this:

```
{"genre": {"country": "taylor swift", "rock": "aimee"}}
```

I run into problems.

My code looks like this:

Go:

```
type Music struct {
  Genre struct { 
    Country string
    Rock string
  }
}

resp := Music{
  Genre: { // error on this line.
    Country: "Taylor Swift",
    Rock: "Aimee",
  },
}

js, _ := json.Marshal(resp)
w.Write(js)
```

However, I get the error

`Missing type in composite literal`

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Here's the composite literal for your type:

```
resp := Music{
    Genre: struct {
        Country string
        Rock    string
    }{ 
        Country: "Taylor Swift",
        Rock:    "Aimee",
    },
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/wxBD9U2430)

You need to repeat the anonymous type in the literal. To avoid the repetition, I recommend defining a type for Genre. Also, use field tags to specify lowercase key names in the output.

```
type Genre struct {
  Country string `json:"country"`
  Rock    string `json:"rock"`
}

type Music struct {
  Genre Genre `json:"genre"`
}

resp := Music{
    Genre{
        Country: "Taylor Swift",
        Rock:    "Aimee",
    },
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/wYA3O31KFs)

Comment: Pretty helpful. Worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Use JsonUtils. It is a program that generates Go structures from a json file:
https://github.com/bashtian/jsonutils

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the json param for the struct values?
https://play.golang.org/p/n6aJdQgfom

Comment: In your GO Playground example, could you add in some comments as well?